# Splitting read/write for mysql cluster with HAproxy

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, reverse-proxy, haproxy, portforwarding

I have a mysql cluster on ubuntu 16.04 and want to split read/write with haproxy.

All connections will be done through port 80.
If someone connects to the server with X.X.X.X/write I want him to be redirected to 1 specific server. 
So far this is my config which works for the default (anything but /write) but when trying to connect with /write I get "unknown MySql server host". 
My config is as follows:

```
global
log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
maxconn 2000
user haproxy
group haproxy

defaults
mode tcp
log global
retries 2
timeout connect 3000
timeout server 5000
timeout client 5000

backend read
balance roundrobin
server mysql1 192.168.0.4:3306
server mysql2 192.168.0.5:3306
server mysql3 192.168.0.6:3306

backend write
server mysql1 192.168.0.4:3306

frontend local
bind *:80
acl write url_beg /write
use_backend write if write
default_backend read
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "URL" in a MySQL connection, so `url_beg` can't possibly match anything.  Connecting to a MySQL server (or proxy) is done by IP address or hostname only -- not hostname and path, because there is no path.  Detecting the hostname the client used is impossible, because it is not passed when the connection is established.

To accomplish what you want, you need two different hostnames, pointing to two different IP addresses on the HAProxy server, and each of these two IPs in its own individual `frontend` with `bind` statement.

```
frontend read
  mode tcp
  bind 203.0.113.1:3306
  default_backend read

frontend write
  mode tcp
  bind 203.0.113.2:3306
  default_backend write
```

Comment: Gotcha. Is there no way to accomplish this without a second ip address?

Comment: You'll have to bind to different ports in that case, because with only one IP there is no other way to differentiate between the targets.